# goalng oauth2: cannot fetch token: "client_id cannot be null"

Tags: go, oauth-2.0

I am working on OAuth2 authentication, Here is the code snippet for that,

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
)

var (
    ctx  context.Context
    conf = &oauth2.Config{
        RedirectURL:  "http://localhost:3001/ApiCallback",
        ClientID:     "C1c179367105720f145aecefa4fafdd587f3",
        ClientSecret: "ff3abcfad5acfe03ff64e9ca56c636e72b12",
        Scopes:       []string{"all"},
        Endpoint: oauth2.Endpoint{AuthURL: "https://api.example.com/v1/authorize",
            TokenURL: "https://api.example.com/v1/access_token",
        },
    }
    url = conf.AuthCodeURL("state", oauth2.AccessTypeOnline)
)

func main() {

    ctx = context.Background()
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/ApiLogin", handleOAuthAPILogin)
    http.HandleFunc("/ApiCallback", handleAPICallback)
    fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":3001", nil))

    fmt.Printf("Visit the URL for the auth dialog: %v", url)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func handleOAuthAPILogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Came to Spark Login")
    http.Redirect(w, r, url, http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
}

func handleAPICallback(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    fmt.Println("Came to Callback")
    code := r.FormValue("code")

    fmt.Println("Auth Code:", code)
    fmt.Println("Client ID:", conf.ClientID)
    fmt.Println("Client Secret:", conf.ClientSecret)

    token, err := conf.Exchange(ctx, code)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Code exchange failed with '%s'\n", err)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
    }
    fmt.Println("Token Code:", token)
}
```

Using above code snippet, 
I am able to get the code(Authorization code) after log in, but it is failing while it exchanges that code. It is throwing the error saying that "client_id" is null.

I have verified my "conf" object , there are values exist.

But it still throws this error. Can any one please help me to fix this

Here is the output

```
$ go run main.go
Came to Spark Login
Came to Callback
Auth Code: YzdjZGZmZTgtYTllYi00zQ1OTI2OTNiZTQtYmQx
Client ID: C1c179367145aecefa4fafdd587f3
Client Secret: ff3abcfad5acfe034b9531ff64e9ca56c636e72b12
Code exchange failed with '%s'
 oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request
Response: {"errorCode":0,"message":"client_id cannot be null","errors":[{"errorCode":0,"description":"client_id cannot be null"}],"trackingId":"NA_3ca9eb7e-f3ce-406
2-8c29-7030ea9b1a08"}
```

Comment: Please `fmt` your code before posting it... that was a pain to fix for you.

Comment: I did fmt the code. It is displaying properly now. Have you seen it same way?

Comment: Is the OAuth server "broken" (i.e. does it expect client_id and client_secret to be passed via query parameters instead of basic auth.)? If so, you need to first call [`oauth2.RegisterBrokenAuthHeaderProvider`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#RegisterBrokenAuthHeaderProvider).

Comment: Awesome. It worked after adding that.
Thanks Tim